# Playing audio files one by one after setting them in a loop

Tags: java, android, sqlite, media-player

I have approximately 6236 Audio files. What I am doing is that I am getting `int` values from the Database and setting them in loop. For Example after query I got 1 in 'a' and 7 in 'b'. Now I tried to used them in loop like `for(int i=a;i<=b;i++)` and passed it in my Path to play Audios one by one but 7 audios playing at a time. I am setting values dynamically from database in loop.What I want to do is to just play them one by one but I am stuck.
Here is my Code:

```
    DatabaseAccess db=DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    db.open();
    mycursor= db.getblindfirst(newid);
    scursor= db.getblindlast(newid);
    scursor.moveToFirst();
    mycursor.moveToFirst();
    a= mycursor.getInt(0);
     b=scursor.getInt(0);

                for (int i=a;i<=b;i++){
                try {


                    mPlayer.setDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/audio/aya(" + i + ").mp3");

                    mPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mPlayer.start();

            }


    db.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are playing all the files at once. You should put the code that should run when the music is completed in the OnCompletionListener.

```
DatabaseAccess db=DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
db.open();
mycursor= db.getblindfirst(newid);
scursor= db.getblindlast(newid);
scursor.moveToFirst();
mycursor.moveToFirst();
a= mycursor.getInt(0);
b=scursor.getInt(0);
mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
try {
    mPlayer.setDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/audio/aya(" + a + ").mp3");
    mPlayer.prepare();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
mPlayer.start();
a++;
mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        if (a!=b) {
            if(mPlayer != null) {
                if(mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mPlayer.stop();
                }
                mPlayer.reset();
            }
            try {
                mPlayer.setDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/audio/aya(" + a + ").mp3");
                mPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mPlayer.start();
            a++;
        }
    }
});
db.close();
}
```

Comment: thanks 4 your reply but app is crashing. Its saying error on mPlayer.Start();  At just after try..

Comment: Its Null Pointer Exception: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference

Comment: mPlayer is not initialized.

Comment: I initialized it globally! And if its not initialized then how can i even run the code??

Comment: Error is on the first mPlayer.Start(); or second?

Comment: On First mPlayer.Start().

Comment: try this before try(), `mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();`

Comment: Its now playing. But only my first audio playing 6 to 7 times.

Comment: the value of variable a is not changing in the OnCompletionListener.

Comment: I know, a++ not working.. But why? What can i do now? :(

Comment: enter this below setDataSource in OnCompletionListener and see if value of a changes `Log.d("OnCompletionListener", "a: "+a);` in the log

Comment: I tried everything. Even log is not showing. just Printing Mediaplyer is playing :1 again and again

Comment: may be OnCompletionListener is not being called.

Comment: Its calling. Because I tried to debug. Its going in the On CompleteListener. and also throwing Exception: Illegal state exception

Comment: Dont you think that if conditition should replaced with while?

Comment: Now Only first 2 audios playing Correctly. Nd then its stop.

Comment: try now, now we are just resetting the MediaPlayer to its idle state before starting again.

Comment: Actually what i understand is that its playing successfully First audio, and after Increament, in On complete listener , playing Second Audio. Now its not going back.